# How to get back clear command if we assign a value to it (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, built-in functions can be assigned a variable value like `plot = 5`. From then on the function `plot()` will not be available. `plot(x)`, for a variable `x`, will give a compilation error. To get back the function we just have to delete the variable `plot` by using `clear plot`.

`clear` is the command usually used to get back the built-in function.

My question is if we assign a value (scalar or matrix) to the function `clear`, how do we get back the function `clear`?

`clear clear` won't obviously work. I couldn't think of a way to get the function back, other than closing and restarting MATLAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned its very bad practice to shadow matlab functions like `clear` - however in this case you can use `builtin` to *clear* your `clear` variable:

```
>> clear = 1
>> whos
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  clear      1x1                 8  double              

>> builtin clear
>> whos
>>
```

To only `clear` `clear` use:

```
builtin clear clear
```

Comment: Thanks man. This helps. I was helping a friend debug a code where `max` was assigned a value. He asked me the above mentioned question then.

Answer (score 1):

No, `clear` is the function to clear, delete, a variable. if you `clear` the variable that was "shadowing" your function, then the function can be found again. if you "shadow" the `clear` function, then you have no way of clearing anything anymore!

It is **very bad practice** to name things `plot` `clear` `surf` `conv` or any other MATLAB function, because of shadowing problems, and you clearly discovered why.

## Never shadow a variable in MATLAB!

---

@Jucobs gives a very nice hint in the comments. Use [`exist`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). It will return a different value if the thing is a variable (1) or a function (2,5)

Comment: You might want to mention [`exist`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html).

Comment: I know that it's a bad practice. I was explaining an error in a code to a friend. And then he asked me what happens if `clear` is assigned a value.